# Cannot update after install master-pdf-editor

Tags: master-pdf-editor

I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu and I have downloaded and installed Master PDF editor from https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/ via the .deb package.

After installation, i cannot run command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and received this message

> E: The package master-pdf-editor needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

what should I do te resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you install with the deb package? How did you install it?

Comment: yes i did. But i have it fixed.
thanks anyway mate

Comment: If you've fixed it, it's encouraged to answer your own questions here. Write up a [good one](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) and drop me a comment when your done and I'll upvote! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you opened and installed the .deb via the software center you can simply click the reinstall button in the upper right corner as shown here:

[image: reinstall-mpe]

Alternatively you can find the location that you downloaded it to with `sudo find / -name "master-pdf-editor*"`
The result **in my case** is:
`/tmp/mozilla_me0/master-pdf-editor-4.1.30_qt5.amd64.deb`

Your path and filename will be different (I'm using the 64-bit version.)

and simply reinstall with `dpkg` for example.

`sudo dpkg -i /tmp/mozilla_me0/master-pdf-editor-4.1.30_qt5.amd64.deb

**Update:** It appears that master-pdf-editor went commercial on or about version 5 in April of 2019 as reported [here.](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/download-master-pdf-editor-4-for-linux.html)

Comment: As you discovered, Master PDF Editor is commercial software so cannot be updated the way free software is.

Comment: @DonP There's a demo version. There are currently no limitations except for the addition of a watermark on the output file. To the best of my knowledge there was a change reported on or about April of 2019, almost 2 years after this answer was originally written. Updating answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the update and yes I know that but I was referring to the registered version. Actually, I came across this post while trying to solve an update issues with the latest version of the same software.